# Can I run an app on a real device (iPhone) from a laptop (mac) with Appium - WebDriver?

Tags: java, iphone, ios, webdriver, appium

I already achieved to run my test cases on the iPhone/iPad Simulator with Appium.

*With simulators:*

```
capabilities.setCapability("device", "iPhone Simulator");
capabilities.setCapability("app", "Safari");
```

Now I'm trying to execute some test using the iPhone web browser on a real device so I set the UDID number.

*With real device:*

```
capabilities.setCapability("device", "75cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
capabilities.setCapability("app", "Safari");
```

but, appium needs an absolute path for that app.

I'm  also trying with Appium GUI and I have same result. I don't known if it's possible to run iPhone apps with Appium on a real devices or not. If it is possible, can anybody tell me which absolute path I need?

Sorry my english.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The absolute path is a filepath to an application *on your Mac* that Appium will grab and install before starting the test you are trying to run. Currently the way that people are making this work for getting Mobile Safari open is using an absolute path to a program like [SafariLauncher](https://github.com/budhash/SafariLauncher) which opens Mobile Safari for you. After that happens you can retrieve the window handle of the webview within Safari and start running normal WebDriver commands.

This workaround is discussed at length [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appium-discuss/zvlozl6NQRs). I can confirm that it works, but the timing of all these components working together is a bit janky, speaking from my testing experience.

For reference, I believe these are the capabilities that I used to get myself up and running.

```
capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.valueOf("MAC"));
capabilities.setBrowserName("iPhone");
capabilities.setCapability("app", "/path/to/SafariLauncher.app");
```

Comment: Thanks Christopher for your answer.
I'll try that with SafariLauncher.
Thanks again.

Comment: At the time of writing (Appium 0.12.13), it seems that passing 'safari' to the 'app' capability is [supposed to work](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/caps.md). It didn't work for me though: `ENOENT, stat './build/SafariLauncher/SafariLauncherSim.zip'`. Looks like Appium is trying to apply the workaround for me and failing. Passing the absolute path to that zip does still work though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes its possible to run Appium for real  devices like IPhone IPad.

**Note**:

1. Appium latest version, ios_webkit_debug_proxy latest and running.
2. Testing device should be added, in the provisioning profile and use that while building your app in XCODE.

**Try this:**
For ios_webkit_debug_proxy command should be

```
"ios_webkit_debug_proxy -c <<deviceID>>:27753 -d"
```

Appium connect to ios_webkit at this port 27753  for devices.

In the APPIUM GUI give:

1. Choose the app location (.app or .ipa) file
2. Give the UDID of the device you connected
3. Mention the bundle ID of the app (as mentioned in the XCODE)
4. Set the XCODE location setting in the APPIUM Preferences.

In Code:

1. Capabilities only need (BROWSER_NAME, PLATFORM, DEVICE=IPad/IPhone
   etc)
2. No need to mention app location from code.

Start ios_webkit_debug_proxy >> Start APPIUM >> START TEST CASE.

Answer (score 0):

1. First when you are using Real device create provisioning profile and run the app and get its .app file
2. Open the appium application browse the .app file check force device iPhone
3. Specify the bundle identifier that you gave while creating provisioning profile
4. Specify the device UDID
5. Click on launch u can find the appium running your app just click appium inspector you can see the app lauching on real device.